# Why don't integers get lifted to doubles when treated as objects and comparing?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, int, double

I ran across this interesting situation today:

```
var a = new HashSet<Object> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
a.Contains(1);     //False
a.Contains(1.0);   //True
```

Of course, this was just a generic version of this:

```
Object b = 2.0;
b.Equals(2);            //False
b.Equals(2.0);          //True
```

I realize the reason for this is because if I write `2.0 == 2`, the C# compiler secretly inserts a cast from integer to double, and by using an Object intermediate, the compiler doesn't have enough information to do this.

My question is, doesn't the *runtime* have enough information to lift the integer to double for the comparison? If the C# compiler assumes it's desirable enough to have an implicit conversion, why shouldn't the JIT have similar behavior?

Comment: JIT != runtime. If you want this thing to work, you want to figure it out at runtime, not during JIT compilation. And if you want it "figured" at runtime, there's a word for that: dynamic. Use sparingly.

Comment: I would recommend this be a community wiki post as there isn't necessarily a specific solution that resolves the problem

Comment: @user414076 This isn't a "why doesn't my code run" question. It's a "why did they choose to implement it this way" question.

Comment: @galford13x: there are no longer Community Wiki questions.

Comment: @John, Interesting I hadn't realized.  Good to know.

Answer (score 4):

C# has to work the way the language specification says that it works. This has nothing to do with the Jitter, which just has to implement the language specification.

The C# language specification says how `==` must work.

The CLR specification says how `Equals()` must work.

There was actually an interesting change made between .Net 1.1 and .Net 2.0.

In .Net 1.1, `3f.Equals(3) == false`.

In .Net 2.0, `3f.Equals(3) == true.`

This is not that same as the *object* comparing version of `Equals()`. Shows you how subtle this kind of thing is.

An interesting (but very old) blog about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/03/23/401038.aspx

It actually does have a few details that do relate to your question, so it's worth a read.

Comment: I consider it unfortunate that the `Object` method uses the same name as type-specific equals methods, since the former is supposed to define an equivalence relation, but the existence of the latter means that no type `T` into which widening conversions exist can very well assure that for all `X` of type `T` and `Y` of arbitrary type, `X.Equals(Y)` will match `Y.Equals(X)`.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a specific programming language with specific semantics for handling `2.0 == 2`, defined in the ECMA-334 standard. The Common Language Runtime (CLR) is an execution environment defined by the ECMA-335 standard, and operates on bytecode, not C# source code. The semantics of these differ in many ways, so while the runtime portion *could* have been implemented to automatically perform widening conversions for these types of comparisons, it *wasn't* actually done that way.

The specific comparison done here happens to be calling [`Double.Equals(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5fbaw6.aspx), which returns

> `true` if *obj* is an instance of `Double` and equals the value of this instance; otherwise, false.

Comment: Yes, I was asking if there was a published reason for not doing so.

Comment: The additional type checks would have a performance impact at runtime, even on code where the user did not need or want the support for lifting values. The current definition provides the minimal support necessary for comparing `double` values without incurring unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This feels more like a community question rather than one looking for a specific solution.  But I'll be happy to weight in.

First, I'll start by saying double equality comparison is already dangerous as I'm sure you might know.  There are tons of information out there on the subject of

```
if(doubleNum == doubleNum2)
```

but also consider should two object of different types that are not relatives be equatable?  While writing the code the compiler can assume some basic ideas.  But the first thing most .Equals(object) methods do is check for type compatibility and if they are not compatible then a false is returned.  I would assume this is the case here as the b.Equals(2) assumes an int Type is passed which is not a double.

After looking at the double.Equals(object) method, you'll notice the first thing it does is check to see if the passed object is a double.  Due to it being an Int32, the function returns false.

While the other answers are more at the reasons the implementation is how it is.  The above should explain why the run time behaves how it does.